# removing event listeners for all elements inside html collection

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I am working on this new project in which I need to add and remove event listeners to the HTML collection elements like so:

```
function Gameboard(){
    const board = [[Cell(),Cell(),Cell()],[Cell(), Cell(), Cell()],[Cell(), Cell(), Cell()]]
    const getBoard = () => board;
    const addToken = (row, column) => {
      board[row][column] = "token";
    } 
    // this is the board display container
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    const cells = container.children;

    return {getBoard, addToken, cells}
}

const board = Gameboard()
```

This is only a portion of the Gameboard function so if you need further clarification I can provide.

The final `const board = Gameboard()` variable declaration is the one that is used in the below code.

```
const playGame = () => {
        for (let i=0; i<board.cells.length; i++){
            const listener = (e) => {
                if(e.target.innerText===""){
                    const row = Math.floor(i/3);
                    const column = i%3;
                    board.addToken(row, column, activePlayer.token)
                    if(!checkGameOver()){
                        switchPlayerTurn()
                    }
                    else{
                        for(let j=0; j<board.cells.length; j++){
                            board.cells[j].removeEventListener("click", listener)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            board.cells[i].addEventListener("click", listener)
        }
    }
```

So here I want to remove event listeners for every cells[] element.

I tried to loop through the html collection inside the event listener and remove every event listener but it only removes the event listener of the element that caused the checkGameOver function to be true

Comment: The listener argument to `removeEventListener()` has to be the same function that was added with `addEventListener()`. This won't work if the listener is created dynamically in a loop. It needs to be a function with a permanent name.

Comment: Do you really need to remove the event listener? Why not just have the listener check some state to determine whether it should take action?

Comment: For instance, you could have a global variable `gameInProgress` that the listener function checks.

Comment: in addition, by using event delegation you can have only one event listener on the parent element (the board probably). [learn more](https://codedamn.com/news/javascript/event-delegation-in-javascript-complete-guide)